# Error when logging to Magento connect manager

Tags: magento

I am getting the following error when I log into Magento connect Manager.

```
Exception caught:
 Unknown error (8192): Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/nirmal/public_html/magento/downloader/pearlib/php/PEAR/Registry.php on line 774
```

The php version I am using is 5.3. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is because eregi() function is deprecated

> Warning
>
> This function has been DEPRECATED as
>   of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature
>   is highly discouraged.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php

Here is a fix of this problem

http://www.devcomments.com/magento-and-deprecated-errors-solved-to290776.htm

Here is also a very similar issue and fix. Take a look here

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/59208/

Comment: True, but it seems to be in the `pearlib` core, not the OP's own code. Not sure whether I'd go hacking around in that

Comment: It is a magento bug but OP can go inside the code and can do hacking

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, this is tricky. This is a so-called `E_DEPRECATED` notice, pointing out a function call that still works, but will be removed in one of the coming versions of PHP.

You could manually edit the code to fix this, but it seems to be in a core part of Magento or the PEAR client. It is likely to be fixed in a future version of Magento. Turning off error reporting for E_DEPRECATED notices *might* be justified in this case.

The error_reporting setting for that would be

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

Comment: The only thing I'd add to this is that Magento Connect runs on a separate stack of framework code, and it's error reporting level is set in a different place.  As such, its much safer to diddle with the existing levels in the *downloader/Maged/Pear.php* file.

Answer (score 0):

The core of this problem is that Magento still doesn't officially support the PHP 5.3 branch as far as I am aware. Since the framework catches even quasi-serious errors and kills execution, you may discover many such bugs.

The easy fix is to use the current 5.2.X version of PHP.